# primefaces extension JSF1064 Unable to find or serve resource documentviewer/viewer.html

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I m using :
-primefaces-extensions\3.1.0\primefaces-extensions-3.1.0.jar
-Java 7
-tomcat 7

In my xhtml file, i declared this code:

```
<p:commandLink id="downloadLink" ajax="true" title="#{document.name}"  action="#{documentSearchController.createDocumentViewer()}"  style="color: black !important; text-decoration: none;" 
 oncomplete="PF('dlg01').show(); return false;"  update="documentViewerDialog pdfvisualizer">

    <h:outputText value="#{document.name}"  style="font-weight: bold;"></h:outputText>

  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{document}"  target="#{documentSearchController.view.selectedDocument}" />   

 <p:dialog showEffect="fold" hideEffect="fold" header="#{document.name}" id="documentViewerDialog" widgetVar="dlg01" modal="true" dynamic="true"  > 
 <pe:documentViewer  height="400" width="800" id="pdfvisualizer"   value="#{documentSearchController.view.contentViewer}" download="#{document.name}"/>
    </p:dialog> 

     </p:commandLink>
```

contentViewer is an StreamedContent. This is my Java Code:

DocumentSearchController.java

```
  public void createDocumentViewer() {
    LOGGER.debug("Downloading document...");
    DocumentVo selectedDoc = getView().getSelectedDocument();
    if (selectedDoc != null && selectedDoc.getOriginal() != null) {
      InputStream is = rechercheFacade.findById(selectedDoc.getOriginal().getId());
      getView().setContentViewer(new DefaultStreamedContent(is, selectedDoc.getOriginal().getMimeType(),
          selectedDoc.getName()));
    }
  }
```

when calling the documentViewer, i have this exception:

```
JSF1064 : Impossible de localiser ou de servir une ressource, documentviewer/viewer.html, depuis la bibliothèque primefaces-extensions.
janv. 26, 2018 4:28:46 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
AVERTISSEMENT: 
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:396)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:421)
```

In org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer (line 42) , when evaluating the value of:

```
writer.writeAttribute("src", generateSrc(context, documentViewer), null);
```

i had this :

javax.faces.resource/documentviewer/viewer.html.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=3.1.0&file=%2FmyProject-web%2Fjavax.faces.resource%2Fdynamiccontent.properties.xhtml%3Fln%3Dprimefaces%26pfdrid%3Dsh1wqWH16DaeFl8tcXfihvHXqz3pBhmdR6eEyycy7B7SwznPx8mFNkrUrcHPPCkZ%26pfdrt%3Dsc%26pfdrid_c%3Dfalse%26uid%3D46a67391-d1c0-486c-8069-17f91c31272d#locale=fr

I find many posts that they have the same problems, but no one gives the answer

Comment: Don't know about your problem, but putting a dialog inside a commandLink is extremely weird.

Comment: I tried to put the dialog outside the commandLink, but the same exception persist. It seems that the documentViewer component start uploading the pdf document and there is  something which interrupt the connection.

Comment: You're not using Internet Explorer, are you? It has this behavior: starts loading resources, decides to change a document (compatibility) mode, aborts requests, starts new ones.

Comment: Hi, it 's the same behaviour in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I decompiled primefaces Extension 3.1.0. The viewer.html exists on primefaces-extensions-3.1.0\META-INF\resources\primefaces-extensions\documentviewer. Do you not thing that it is a web.xml configuration ?